# Publisher subscriber pattern with hash table

Tags: c#

I have seen several implementation of the Publisher subscriber pattern using a list to store all the receiver.

But none of them was using hash table.

Therefore, I am wondering why ? Is there any reason why we should not use hash table for this purpose ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Hashtable` optimizes lookups. Here you can find typical use cases: http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable

In your task you just need to iterate all the subscribers, so any collection which implements `IEnumerable<T>` interface can be used, but there's no need for `Hashtable`

Comment: Although, if your list of subscribers gets big, you could use a generic Dictionary to group subscribers by type or some other common factor to optimise the process of finding the relevant ones.

Comment: Well for unsubribing you do need to look up, so every Publisher subscriber pattern should use hash table in my opinion

Comment: @DavidOsborne theoretically, yes. But I can't think of a real-world example where pub/sub message filtering is really needed. It always must be splitted in different parts or redisigned I think

Comment: @taktak004 Right, that is what I missed. But I recommend you to be sure that unsubscribing is a real overhead. One of performance kicks of using `Hashset` is computing a hash (you need to compute it twice for sub / unsub).